# Gatsby : image load then disapear on netlify. Works fine on my computer with gatsby develop and works fine on Zeit

Tags: gatsby, netlify, vercel

I made a basic blog to test Gatsby and Netlify CMS.

I have a very strange problem.

The logo of the blog disappear when the page is fully loaded.
This happened only on Netlify. 
With the "`Gatsby Develop`" command, there is no problems.

I tested to host the blog with `Zeit`, and the pictures doesn't disappear.

Netlify : https://wonderful-dubinsky-d2e0f3.netlify.com/
Zeit : https://recettes-ecru.now.sh/

Both website use the same Github repository.

Comment: Both links look identical.

Comment: Do you see a picture in the header of the website on both link ?

Comment: Here is a video of this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_WyNzcUSvA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Yes the image is in the header on both links. The small image is in the header once i click through to an article on both links as well.

Comment: Is it possible that the error is related to the CDN and appear only in a part of the world ? Because i tested the website on multiple computer.

Comment: I'm not sure. Both zeit now and netlify websites seem to state that they invalidate the CDN cache on each deployment

Comment: How can you check that ? thanks for helping.

Comment: The issue was related to the service worker on the site. After unregistering my service worker, it was solved : https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-understanding-unregistering-service-workers/145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i discovered that the problem was related to service worker.
I was using gatsby-plugin-offline. This plugin makes a Gatsby site work offline by using a service worker.

Browsers cache service workers for 24 hours by default, and don’t update them when you reload your page.

After unregistering my service worker, the problem was solved.

Useful reading here : 
https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-understanding-unregistering-service-workers/145

How to uninstall a service worker : 
https://love2dev.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-a-service-worker/